# Remove blue border of ListboxItem when MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, border

I have been trying to remove blue box when mouse is over item in Listbox and I ran out of ideas, perhaps you will come out with any. Thank you in advance.[image]

simple Listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Mylist}" />
```

Unfortunately, solution below does not work

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lista}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is dictated by the Control template.

If you're familiar with XAML, right click the ListBox, go to `Edit Template -> Edit Copy...` Check for `Border` tags.

In order to help you, check this link as well:[ListBox Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Make your reply more precise.

Comment: Chris W response completes mine.

Answer (score 0):

New problem came out, I acquired listbox without blue border

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

but I have set ItemContainerStyle like this

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ContainerStyle">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource not_mouseover}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource mouseover}"/>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lista}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}">
```

and in this case it turns out that it does not work(I mean blue border turns up as previously). If I set ItemTemplate to any of specified DateTemplate it works fine, but here not. Do you happen to know why?
I sorted this out. Just one style for ListboxItem

```
<Style x:Key="item_template" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_mouseover}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource control_not_mouseover}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>           
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding lista}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource item_template}"> 
    </ListBox>
```

and declared ControlTemplate in order to remove blue borders

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="control_not_mouseover" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <ContentPresenter
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource not_mouseover}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="control_mouseover" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <ContentPresenter
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource mouseover}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Maybe someone will take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

Styles with no `x:Key` are meant to work in all TargetType controls. 
For example:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
 </Style>
```

Will work every time you set a new `Button` control. So, if you insert a `Button` without specifying a style like this: `<Button/>` it will have a *green* Background, as specified above.

On the other hand:

```
 <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="myButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
 </Style>
```

Will only work for `Button` controls that specifies the `Style` template.
i.e: `<Button Style="{StaticResource myButton}" />` -> This `Button` will have a green background and all other Buttons will have the default background color.

My advice is: always set a x:Key in your styles so you can set them later. In your scenario, put the `x:Key="ContainerStyle"` at the first code and remove the Style declared later. It should work.

Comment: I updated my previous message where solution is included. Thanks for effort and sacrificed time.

Comment: Was my answer above useful? If so, can you set it as answer? Thanks and great work there!